# TypeScript Map: Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'

Tags: typescript, typeerror

I have the typescript code below in VS Code,

```
const hash: Map<string, number> = new Map<string, number>([
    ['Small', 1],
    ['Medium', 2],
    ['Large', 3],
]);
const sz = 'Small';
const num: number = hash.has(sz) ? hash.get(sz) : 0;
```

It keeps complaining:

***Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.***

Not sure anything I did wrong here. Doesn't hash.has(sz) already ensure hash.get(sz) won't be undefined?

My current approach is to use **const num: number = hash.has(sz) ? hash.get(sz)! : 0;** but it doesn't seem to be a graceful to me.

What's the proper way to fix this kind of issue?

Comment: The compiler doesn't know that `hash.has(sz)` has any impact on `hash.get(sz)`; see [ms/TS#13086](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13086).  The language can't model this well; you *could* change things so that `hash.has(sz)` returning `true` would imply `hash.get(sz)` is defined, but that would persist even after a `hash.delete(sz)`, which would be bad.

Comment: Ah yes...ms/TS#13086 is exactly same scenario as mine, so I suppose using const num: number = hash.get(sz) ?? 0; as Simon suggested should be the right way to go, Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const hash: Map<string, number> = new Map<string, number>([
    ['Small', 1],
    ['Medium', 2],
    ['Large', 3],
]);
const sz = 'Small';
const num: number = hash.get(sz) ?? 0;
```

This should do it. `Map.prototype.get` returns undefined if it can't find the key, which we can null coalesce into 0.

Comment: This is the right way to proceed; see [ms/TS#13086](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13086) for a discussion on the situation.

Comment: Thanks! That works!

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the comma from the 3rd element of the array:  ['Large', 3]

Comment: Extra commas are perfectly legal and recommended by many style guides.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an attempt to answer the question.

Comment: I guess removing the comma was a bad suggestion, but since trailing commas cannot be used in JSON i think its just a bad practice.  I think it kills sql as well.